# Spotfire Cross Table show/hide 'n' rows when 2 or more columns (groups/hierarchy)

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a property control that I use to limit show/hide rows in a Spotfire cross table. It works fine if when there is one column. However, when I have two columns it limits the total rows to shown to the value in show/hide but I would like it to show/hide that many rows per group/hierarchy (when 2 or more columns are involved). I am currently manipulating the table with IronPython so if there's a method I'm unaware of to set then I can use that as a solution, too.

Comment: Please provide some details, with an example, and add your ironpython script

Comment: I don't have an issue with my script. I'm asking if it is even possible to show/hide N' rows in a crosstable when two or more columns on the Y-axis are selected. So if in CrossTable settings we set Show Rows to 3 then there would be 3 per hierarchy group, not just 3 for the entire crosstable (this is how it currently functions). If it is possible whether GUI or IronPython then I will look further but I have not found the capability to be available.

Comment: How do you select the 3 rows per hierarchy? Are they the max of the hierarchy?

Comment: The values are sorted in descending order. There are 4 values columns and my property control drop-down determins which of the 4 columns to sort by running an IronPython script each time the property control changes. I've thought about adding into my script some sort of ranking over both Y-axis groups and then just Limit Data by [my_grp_rank] <= 'N' but it's a bit overkill for what I need. If it was something as simple as attaching a property control to a Show/Hide then that's quick and easy. I pretty much want to know if there is either a GUI option to show/hide per group.